# Contar valores True em um Objeto

Tags: php, array, objetos

tenho esse retorno de uma API:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'data' => 
    object(stdClass)[44]
       public 'id' => float 3.5795374673835E+14
       public 'completed' => boolean false
       public 'name' => string 'Dia dos Namorados' (length=17)
```

E eu gostaria de contar quantos projetos estão com a chave **`completed => true`**, como eu posso fazer isso?

Exemplo:

```
if ( $objeto->completed == true )
{
  $contar++;
}
```

Comment: Isso não funciona? qual é o problema? tentou `$objeto->data->completed` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta fazer um loop e contar os itens, com o foreach você consegue. Veja como ficou:

```
<?php

$object = (object) array(
    'data' => (object) array(
        44 => (object) array(
           'id' => 3.5795,
           'completed' => false,
           'name' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor.',
        ),
        45 => (object) array(
           'id' => 3.5796,
           'completed' => false,
           'name' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor.',
        ),
        46 => (object) array(
           'id' => 3.5797,
           'completed' => true,
           'name' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor.',
        ),
        47 => (object) array(
           'id' => 3.5798,
           'completed' => false,
           'name' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor.',
        ),
    )
);

$countTrue = 0;
$countFalse = 0;

foreach($object->data as $item)
{
    if($item->completed){
        $countTrue ++;
    } else {
        $countFalse++;
    }

}

echo "Itens como true: " . $countTrue; // 1
echo "Itens como false: " . $countFalse; // 3

?>
```

Exemplo [Ideone](https://ideone.com/iqXWRe).

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in: **Obs: Já tentei mudar $item->completed para $item['completed']**

Comment: @MustacheWeb, este código deve estar dentro do foreach. No seu exemplo eu não sei o nome da variável que está todos os dados, mas assumindo que seja $datas, para acessar um item direto seria: $datas->data->{'44'}->completed. Obs.: Para funcionar dessa forma, a classe deve ser nativa ou que herde do stdClass.